# Need assistance making .htaccess more strict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am looking for assistance in making my .htaccess file point ALL requests to my index.php file, regardless of if the file exists or not. Currently, all requests are sent to index.php UNLESS that file already exists in the directory, which I do not want, nor is secure.

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Let me know if you have any pointers or resources. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you need real path in `path` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try just this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi thank you, could you please explain to me the difference between my previous file and this new one? Shamefully, I copied this previous code.

Comment: Hi @MarshallOfSound, after reviewing your suggestion, this causes an error.

Comment: Sorry fixed the file, missed out the RewriteCond.  The difference is in your the 2 rewrites are for "if file doesn't exist" and "if directory doesn't exist".  This on is for "if not index.php"

Comment: I can reason that this also allows for robots.txt to be found (good for search engines). Thank you!

Comment: unfortunately I am still getting a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: It's `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]`, with `( )` because you use $1.